# What name should I be using for heroku postgres DB?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

In the UI, I note that there are effectively two names of the db. Which one should I be using when trying to make a connection?

This main one:
[image]

And then this one under the credentials section:
[image]

Comment: Note: I've never worked with heroku, but I'm pretty sure you want to use that one, which is also in the URI (a few rows below). Possibly in a `dbname=xyz` format.

Answer (score 1):

You should navigate to Settings in your Heroku account and use the value defined in the `DATABASE_URL` env var.